# unity panel icons not working

Tags: unity, icons

All the custom icon themes I install can change the nautilus icons just fine, but the unity panel always looks like this:

[image]

Except when I set it to the standard Ubuntu mono, that looks normal.

I'm sure the themes I've installed have these icons present, and that the problem is that they are for some reason unable to load them.

How can I fix the problem? I'm using Unity Tweak tool to change them, and downloaded the themes from gnome-look.org if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You could reset unity Icons:

```
unity --reset-icons
```

And Install MyUnity and choose the desired theme:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:myunity/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install myunity
```

[image]

Comment: apt-get is not able to locate the package.

Comment: @user11177 I added the PPA for myunity

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/myunity/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: myunity is not supported on your ubuntu version 13.10

Comment: stick with ubuntu tweak tool

Comment: That's Unity Tweak Tool: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/